# Change Value of Textarea on Select Option Change

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, selection

I have to change the content of textarea on changing select option.for that I have wrote code as follows

```
                <tr><td>Template:</td><td>
                    <select t name="template" onChange = "setTemplate();">
                        <option value="0">Admission</option>
                        <option value="1">Registration</option>
                        <option value="2">Speech on 2,3 May</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            <tr>
                <td>Message: </td>
                <td>
                <textarea name="adminmessage" id="adminmessage" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea></td>
            </tr>           
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send SMS" class="button-primary" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
<script>
            test0 = "";
            test1 = "test string 1";
            test2 = "test string 2";
            function setTemplate() {
                var otionValue = document.form.template.value;
                if (otionValue == "0") {
                  document.form.adminmessage.value = test0;
                } else if (otionValue == "1")
                  document.form.adminmessage.value = test1;
                  else if (otionValue == "2")
              document.form.textarea.value = test2;
            }; 
            </script>
</div>
```

but this is not works. please help me to correct.I have to do this in javascript itself not in jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your javascript syntax is not valid. Check corrected example here it here : http://jsfiddle.net/WkbLP/

**javascript** :

```
<script>
        test0 = "";
        test1 = "test string 1";
        test2 = "test string 2";
        function setTemplate(t) {
            var otionValue = t.value;
            if (otionValue == "0") {
              document.getElementById('adminmessage').innerHTML = test0;
            } else if (otionValue == "1")
              document.getElementById('adminmessage').innerHTML = test1;
              else if (otionValue == "2")
          document.getElementById('adminmessage').innerHTML = test2;
        }; 
</script>
```

**HTML** :

```
<select  name="template" onChange = "setTemplate(this);">
    <option value="0">Admission</option>
    <option value="1">Registration</option>
    <option value="2">Speech on 2,3 May</option>
</select>
```